# How can I operate on successive files using ls and xargs?

Tags: shell, unix, ls, netcdf, xargs

I have a folder full of files where:

`ls *101* | grep -v "discard"`

gives me this:

```
test101v1.nc
test101v2.nc
test101v3.nc
```

Now, I need to concatenate these files which ordinarily I can do using this:

```
ncrcat test101v1.nc test101v2.nc test101v3.nc out.nc
```

How can I do this using `xargs` inside a shell script?

I can use a for loop, but I was wondering if it could be done in a smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `ls *101* | grep "discard" | xargs ncrcat -o out.nc`

or you may use command find:

`find . -type f \( -name "*101" ! -name "*discard*" \) | xargs ncrcat -o out.nc`

Another way to use array like: `ncrcat $(ls *101* | grep "discard") -o out.nc`

Answer (score 1):

Why use xargs? What's wrong with

```
ls *101* | grep -v "discard" | ncrcat -o out.nc
```